# Question related Gödel's constructible universe

Tags: set-theory

I need to show that if $x\in L_\alpha$, where $\alpha>\omega$ is a limit ordinal, then $^nx\in L_\alpha$ for every $n\in\omega$.

So, as $x\in L_\alpha$ we can take an ordinal $\omega<\gamma<\alpha$ such that $x\in L_\gamma$. Now, as $L_\gamma$ is a transitive set we obtain that $x\subseteq L_\gamma$. So, given $a\in x$ we have that: $$\{m,x\}:=\{y\in L_\gamma:L_\gamma\models (y=m\vee y=a)\}\in L_{\gamma+1}.$$

With a similar argument we can obtain that $(m,a)\in L_{\gamma+2}$ for every $m\in\omega$ and $a\in x$. Now, given $f\in^nx$, we have that $f\subseteq L_{\gamma+2}$, then:
$$
f=\{z\in L_{\gamma+2}:L_{\gamma+2}\models\exists m<n(z=(m,f(m)))\}\in L_{\gamma+3}.
$$

So, we have that $^nx\subseteq L_{\gamma+3}$ and then $^nx\in L_{\gamma+4}\subseteq L_{\alpha}$.

I'm reading the Devlin's book *Constructibility*. My problem is that the author claims $^nx\in L_{\gamma+3}$ but I don't see how it is possible. Can someone explain me why it is true?

Thanks

Comment: You should give a page number. I'm guessing if there's anything here, it's that you can show $\{m,a\}\in L_\gamma,$ not just $L_{\gamma+1}.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, the claim is in the end of page 66.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you diverge from Devlin is that he starts by saying $(n,a)\in L_{\gamma+1}$ whereas you start by saying $\{n,a\}\in L_{\gamma+1}.$ In fact, we do actually have $\{n,a\}\in L_\gamma,$ so Devlin is correct (and optimal). If $x\in L_\gamma$ and $a\in x,$ then $a\in L_\beta$ for some $\beta<\gamma,$ so $\{n,a\}=\{y\in L_\beta : L_\beta\models y=n\lor y=a\}\in L_\gamma.$

Comment: Only one doubt. Here are you assume that $\gamma$ is limit ordinal?

Comment: @Gödel No... why do you say that? (What I say would still be true, but it would trivialize it... furthermore the least such $\gamma$ will never be a limit ordinal, so it would be a weird assumption.)

Comment: I don't see why we can take $a$ in a step before $\gamma$.

Comment: $x\in L_\gamma$. (And say $\gamma$ is a successor.) What is the definition of $L_\gamma$?

Comment: i saw it already. Sorry for my dummy question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gödel No, looking back on it I can see how I should have at least been clear that it was in the predecessor in the successor case. (I suppose I didn't want to preclude the limit case which is why I phrased it the way I did.)